# Active link on a one page website

Tags: jquery

I have a one page website where I need the active link in the menu to be a different colour. 
Is there a way in this code to have it so when a link is clicked on, the background colour doesn't show on all links as is scrolls through the pages.

This is for smooth scrolling and changing the background colour of the links:

```
 $('a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $("html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated)").animate({
        'scrollTop': $(href).offset().top
    }, 700, 'swing');
});
$('#nav a').click(function () {
    $('#nav a').css("background-color", "");
    $(this).css("background-color", "#333333");
});
```

This is for when the user manually scrolls through the page and the background colour on the links change:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var href = $(this).scrollTop();
    $('.link').each(function (event) {
        if (href >= $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top - 1) {
            $('.link').not(this).removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

Here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/MCka4/

Comment: in your .click() function for `#nav a`, set the background color to `none` instead of just blank. If I understand your question correctly, this will remove all background colors then apply the dark grey BG to your active link.

Comment: I tried adding none but this didn't work.

Comment: ahhh stupid me... `background-color`'s default is `transparent `

Comment: Now it worked, but it removed the background colour of the link when I manually scroll through the page. The colour just stays on the last link clicked on.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this easily with CSS
For example you could determine which elements of the navigation are selected with an .active CSS class:

```
#nav a {
    background-color: transparent;
}
#nav a.active {
    background-color: #333333;
}
```

And then you could change your code to use the new CSS class you just created:

```
$('#nav a').click(function () {
    $('#nav a.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var href = $(this).scrollTop();
    $('.link').each(function (event) {
        if (href >= $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top - 1) {
            $('#nav a.active').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried this but I didn't seem to work, the background color still goes through all the links as It scrolls through the pages.